# Windows Share Permissions VS NTFS Permissions Issue

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I'm experiencing some weirdness in Windows Server Share permissions that I cannot explain.  Here's an illustration of my issue:
[image: Windows Share Permission Issue]

- The user has 'Full Control' on the 'Share' permission tab
- The user is not listed at all on the NTFS permissions tab (and, as far as I can tell, they are not in any of the groups listed there. **EDIT**: *actually, they were. See below.*)
- The user can indeed create and modify files inside the shared directory and all sub-directories.
- I am testing this across our network from another server where I am logged on as the user shown with the "Full Control" permissions on the 'Share' tab

My question is, is this normal and expected? Or am I overlooking something? I thought that a user had to have *both* 'Share' and 'NTFS' permissions in order to have access to the shared folders and files.  Can you confirm this behavior, or else tell me what to check/troubleshoot to understand this.   Is this documented Windows Share permission behavior?

Comment: All user accounts are members of the Users group. For a standalone server this is the local Users group. For an AD domain this is the Domain Users group, which is itself a member of the local Users group.

Comment: @joeqwerty, that was the answer.  The ...Users permission line that says "Special" actually was granting access to create folders and files and append data to them.  Once I removed that, I no longer could do anything from the user account granted "Full Access" on the share.  If you submit an answer to this I will give you credit.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All user accounts are members of the Users group. For a standalone server this is the local Users group. For an AD domain this is the Domain Users group, which is itself a member of the local Users group.

Comment: Thanks.  The ...Users permission line that says "Special" actually was granting (all users) access to create folders and files and append data to them. Once I removed that, I no longer could do anything from the user account granted "Full Access" on the share.